# How to read .csv file in Perl to get required fields only, perform some operation and write back the results to same file?

Tags: perl

I have a CSV file which contains *IP, Alive* fields like below:

```
ip, alive
127.0.0.1, Yes
127.0.0.2, No
```

I want to ping each IP and if the ping is reachable then I need to put Yes in front of that IP in same CSV file.
I'm trying with below code, but stuck at reading and writing the same CSV file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::Ping;
use Data::Dumper;

my $file = 'servers.csv';
my @filedata;
open(my $fh, '<', $file) or die "Can't read file '$file' [$!]\n";
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    chomp $line;
    my @fields = split(/,/, $line);
    push @filedata, \@fields;
}
print Dumper(@filedata);    

my $p = Net::Ping->new();

if ($p->ping('127.0.0.1'))
{
   print "\nYes\n";
}
```

My code for ping and reading file is working fine but I'm not much sure about loop through the data read from file and then ping and store the result back to CSV file.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is it necessary to the same file as you are reading from? Either store the contents in memory, and write when done, or write to a different file, and copy it over the original when done.

Comment: @Unixmonkey, Yes. Because my source file is too large and storing the contents of whole file in memory is not efficient for system.

Comment: I would generally use [DBD::CSV](https://perlmaven.com/calculate-bank-balance-take-two-dbd-csv), though I believe that loads the contents of the file into memory. And, generally, that *is* efficient, even at hundreds of MB.

Comment: @Tanktalus, Could you please help me with the code in the form of answer?

Comment: Do you have Text::CSV_XS module installed on the server?

Comment: @Andrey, No. See output: Can't locate Text/CSV.pm

Comment: [Text::AutoCSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::AutoCSV) is another handy one, especially the `field_add_computed` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use Tie::Array::CSV qw();
tie my @file, 'Tie::Array::CSV', 'servers.csv';

for my $server (@file) {
    next if 'ip' eq $server->[0]; # skip table header
    my $ping_result = rand > 0.5 ? 'Yes' : 'No'; # fake ping
    $server->[1] = $ping_result; # update file
}
```

Comment: Getting below error:
Can't locate Tie/Array/CSV.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at test2.pl line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at test2.pl line 1.

I don't have access to install anything on server, even perl modules, Please suggest another way.

Comment: I refuse to. Find a way to install the module. ["Yes, even you can use CPAN"](https://perlmonks.org/?node_id=693828) Copy-paste the module source code as a last resort.

Comment: I already tried CPAN. See below output: cpan -i Tie::Array::CSV
-bash: cpan: command not found

This is high security banking server, so no way to install anything.

Comment: Look, you **can** "install" your script. You do have write permission **somewhere**. Copy the dependent modules into the same place.

Comment: Yes, I can install. Please let me know how can I install without CPAN, because CPAN is not allowed but manual installation is allowed.

Comment: @PrakashG It is incorrect to install CPAN modules without a CPAN client, or your distro's package manager. They handle required things like dependencies and correct install locations. Since Tie::Array::CSV is pure perl and Text::CSV has a pure perl backend option (Text::CSV_PP) then it could be [fatpacked](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::FatPacker), by installing them first on a different machine if necessary and fatpacking them into a script.

Answer (score -1):

I think this does what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::Ping;
use Data::Dumper;
use File::Copy;

my $file = 'servers.csv';
my $fileOut = 'serversOut.csv';

my @filedata;
open(my $fh, '<', $file) or die "Can't read file '$file' [$!]\n";
open(my $fhOut, '>', $fileOut) or die "Can't read file '$fileOut' [$!]\n";
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    chomp $line;
    my @fields = split(/,/, $line);

    my $p = Net::Ping->new();
    if($fields[0] eq 'ip') {
        print "Header $fields[0]\n";
        print $fhOut 'ping, ' . $line . "\n";
        next;
    }
    if ($p->ping($fields[0])) {
        print "Pinging $fields[0] - yes\n";
        print $fhOut 'Yes, ' . $line . "\n";
    }
    else {      
        print "Pinging $fields[0] - no\n";
        print $fhOut 'No, ' . $line . "\n";
    }
}
close $fh;
close $fhOut;   

move($fileOut, $file) or die "Can't move '$fileOut' file '$file' [$!]\n";
```

Comment: It's justified because you did not pay attention to the requirements in the comments attached to the question. Quoted for your convenience: >> Is it necessary to the same file as you are reading from? > Yes.

Comment: Yes, because it is too large to store in memory. My solution does not store the file in memory.